# Из графиков перейти к гистограммам ("step") в matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

У меня есть массив numpy [148,6], который по оси х содержит данные о времени, а по оси у - значения энергии. Это отображено на графике. Мне неоходимо перевести обычные графики в гистограмму. Ниже приведен код для отображения данных.

```
d = pd.DataFrame(Data, index=Time, columns=['e1','e2', 'e3', 'e4', 
'e5', 'e6'])
d.plot(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('E')
plt.title('Title')
plt.show()
```

Графики отображают то, что я имею и то, что должно получиться.
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df.plot(figsize=(12, 6), drawstyle='steps-pre')
```

или так:

```
df.plot(figsize=(12, 6), drawstyle='steps-post')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS `drawstyle` может принимать три варианта:

```
Define where the steps should be placed:

'steps-pre': The y value is continued constantly to the left from every x position, i.e. the interval (x[i-1], x[i]] has the value y[i].
'steps-post': The y value is continued constantly to the right from every x position, i.e. the interval [x[i], x[i+1]) has the value y[i].
'steps-mid': Steps occur half-way between the x positions.
```

Comment: Вы как всегда выручаете, спасибо огромное!

Comment: @u_lialia, всегда рад помочь :)

Comment: А скажите, пожалуйста, есть какой-то способ, чтобы определить форму гистограммы? Например, чтобы начиналось не как  -|(зекальное отражение буквы Г) , а формы __|. Это нужно как-то по-особенному задать начальную точку? В этом мои графики не совпадают..

Comment: @u_lialia, дополнил ответ. Варианты, кроме описанных в ответе, мне незнакомы...

Comment: Помогло, дякую)

Comment: @u_lialia, будь ласка (: